# How to make map tiles load more efficiently using leaflet with an android app?

Tags: android, cordova, dictionary, tiles, leaflet

I am currently developing an android application that features a map using phonegap, cloudmade and leaflet. Is there a way I can somehow cache the map tiles on the android phone? Loading the map tiles from the server each time is quite slow.

Comment: There are a bunch of answers that might help you.  Search for phonegap speeding

Answer (score 2):

This is only theoretic considerations and I don't known working implementations for leaflet. However I have some issue, but don't have time now to resolve it.

**Web and phonegap storages:**

1. `loacalstorage` - synchronous, easy to implement with base64 url, small size 2.5-5MB (probably phonegap resolve `localstorage` small size issue).
2. `indexed db` and `web sql` - asynchronous, size 50 MB (maybe more).
3. phonegap file storage - asynchronous.

**How implement:**

Write own layer which will work with your storage, probably it will be difficult for asynchronous APIs.

You always can store tile as data url with base64 encoding. You can transform image by server url to data url with JS and canvas.

If you can use tile preloading easiest way to use file storage, because you can just use links to tiles on your file system.

For asychronous APIs you always can detect your tile by `zoom`, `latitude` and `longitude`: insert fake tile with `zoom_lat_lng` id and fake `src`, check tile in storage by this id, if tile found - load it, else load from server with caching.

**UPD**: See my caching solution with indexed db and web sql for example:
https://github.com/tbicr/OfflineMap/tree/master/leaflet_idb_sql_site and example http://tbicr.github.com/OfflineMap/leaflet/index.html (now not fast on android).